# Adding offset to each line

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to javascript, so excuse my lack of actual code.

I have a block of text that I want to fit into a space. I want to break it into rows. I need to find where the newlines are to add a new line and some offset. Then I want to subtract the offset from the row word length (if needed) and get a new cycle until there is something to do.

I was actually hoping to get an answer on the splitting on newlines, or at least finding out how long a row is by pixels.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I really don't understand your problem

Comment: I need to basically chop a block of text of some lenght, width and height into rows.
 
and then add to each row increasing indent (padding-left) and cropping overflowing words to next new rows until there is no word left and everything is nicely tipped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use the element offset?

```
<div id="somediv" style="height:20px;width:100px;">
 some content that wrap and makes new line  some content that wrap and makes new line  some content that wrap and makes new line  some content that wrap and makes new line 
</div>

<script>
    var d=document.getElementById("somediv");
    alert(d.style.height);//outputs 20px
    alert(d.offsetHeight);//outputs the actual/rendered height used by the element
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, the only way to check the width of some text is to render that text in a hidden element and then check the width of that element. Continue doing this until you get the longest string which is less than your desired maximum width. Rinse and repeat.

I assume that you're trying to fit your text into an arbitrary/irregular shape: if it's just a rectangle, then of course, you could just set the width of a container element.

Answer (score 0):

To get the width of a row you can use the

[width()](http://docs.jquery.com/CSS/width)

function

and to get the height you can use

[height()](http://docs.jquery.com/CSS/height) function

```
<script>
$(document).ready ( function() {
    alert ( $("#tr1").width() );
    alert ( $("#tr1").height() );
});

</script>
<table>
<tr id="tr1">
<td>test test testtest test testtest test testtest test test
</td>
<td>test test testtest test testtest test testtest test test
</td>
<td>test test testtest test testtest test testtest test test
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```